# core data array as attribute

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I want create attribute of "event" entity that will have a short list of events what the correct way to make it?
I think the right way is just use array but how can I do it? if someone can give me code example it will be nice.

Comment: create one more entity named as `ShortEvent` & use it to point from the original entity `Event` using primary key & foreign key mechanism.

Comment: core data is something new for me, I don't understand what you try to tell me can you explain how to use primary key? or link me to tutorial? 

also I am not sure you understand me as well, I have entity PERSON that will have relation to EVENT that will have type(attribute) when user create new EVENT I just want that he be able choose the type of the event from list (not insert by him self just choose) how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't listen to any advice regarding foreign keys - they do not exist in Core Data. What you have to do is link your `Event` entity to another (or itself) with a **relationship**.

It is not clear why an event would have a short list of events. Maybe you want to distinguish event types or something similar. You could then create a new entity `EventType` and establish a to-many relationship in the Core Data Model Editor:

```
Event <<----->> EventType
```

Now an event could be linked an arbitrary number of `EventType` objects. You could use a relationship name like `allowedEventTypes` for each event and access this set (not an array, mind you, but an `NSSet` with unordered unique objects):

```
NSSet *types = event.allowedEventTypes;
```

Once you master the core data modeling technique, the coding becomes exceedingly simple.